# Open new tab with useNavigate hook in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to navigate with the useNavigate hook and everything is good, but I want it to open the URL in a new tab, and not the current one. Is that possible?

My code:

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
...
...
const navigate = useNavigate();
...
...
<Button onClick={()=>{navigate('/someURL')}}>Open URL</Button>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

you can use `window.open()` method instead of using `navigate()` to open the URL in the new tab. Pass `'_blank'` as a second argument in the function for opening it in new tab.

Importantly!
If the `rel="noopener noreferrer"` attribute is added to the link, the referrer information will not be leaked. The end goal is not to miss the HTTP referrer title when a person clicks on a hyperlink. If there is no information in the title, it will not be tracked by analytical tools.

Example:

```
<Button onClick={()=>window.open('/someURL','_blank', 'rel=noopener noreferrer')}>Open URL</Button>
```

Comment: Note, unlike `navigate`, this will need you to prepend the `basename` you may have passed to the `Router` component.

Comment: simple and sweet ... thanks

Comment: this is working however it's opening the page in a new window. When I remove the parameter `'rel=noopener noreferrer')`, it then opens the page in a new tab

Comment: @D.Rattansingh since 2011, all major browsers adds `noopener` as default when using `target='_blank'`. So it's not neccessary.

Answer (score 7):

A minor enhancement, with `${window.location.origin}` it will navigate you from the ***baseUrl*** (current website domain), otherwise it will take the current **URL** and add the **newRoute** to it.

```
window.open(`${window.location.origin}/${newRoute}`)
```

In addition to window.open have 3 paramerets as per MDN

```
open(url, target, windowFeatures)
```

and the **target** is `'_blank'` by default so no need to add it, for more information you can read MDN doc [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/api/window/open).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't found how to do this with useNavigation, but you can use window.open('your_url','_blank')
That works for me.